# React Native push notifications: what is supposed to trigger push token to be generated?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I'm using `react-native-push-notification` in React Native 0.61.5, on Android. I've followed the installation instructions at [this link](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification), including the `onRegister()` function that is called when the push token is generated. This function is never called. I'm wondering if I'm missing some code necessary to generate it. Does anyone know what exactly triggers the push token to be generated?